# How to handle errors created from de-authorizing your app in Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, laravel-5

I am trying to figure out how to handle error created when a user de-authorizes my Facebook app. I'm using larval 5 and this is the current error I'm getting:

Error validating access token: The user has not authorized application

the access_token is being stored in current session. Is there a way i can use a try and catch statement or any clever solution, so that when I get an access_token that doesn't validate I can still continue with the rest of the code.

below is the code i'm using, it world great infill app gets reauthorized:

```
$token = Session::get('fb_user_access_token');

    $permissionsToRequest = ([
        'public_profile',
        'publish_actions'
    ]);

    $login_link_for_public_actions = $fb->getLoginUrl($permissionsToRequest, 'http://pms.dev:8000/facebook/publicactions/callback');

    if (isset($token)) {

        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($token);
        try {
        // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
        $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=permissions');
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
        }

        // Returns a `Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphUser` collection
        $facebookuser = $response->getGraphUser();
        $ty= json_decode($facebookuser);

        $permissions = $facebookuser['permissions'];

        $checked = '';
        foreach ($permissions as $p) {
            if ($p['permission'] == 'publish_actions' && $p['status'] == 'granted' ) {
            $checked = 'checked';
            }
        }
    } else {
        $checked = null;
    }
```

I narrowed it down to the error coming somewhere from the try catch statement:

```
   try {
        // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
        $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=permissions');
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
        }
```

i'm getting this error in my view : FacebookResponseException in FacebookResponseException.php line 89:

I tried dd() different values inside the catch statements but nothing changes. I think i'm grabbing the wrong exeption , not sure what else to do?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you do not use Socialite? It should handly this stuff for you and is fairly easy to use https://github.com/laravel/socialite

Comment: _“Is there a way i can use a try and catch statement”_ – that’s what the code is already doing (otherwise you would get a fatal error, if the exception wasn’t caught anywhere.) You are already _outputting_ parts of the exception object - so you could as well _check_ its content via an if statement, and if it is this particular exception, do {something}

Comment: @Frank Provost I don't use socialite couse I'm using the app for finding friends and allowing users to post from my site. From my understanding socialite is only for login in the user.

Comment: well sure, it's purpose is a login, however you will receive an oauth token from the validation. You can also claim "friendlist" ( or whatever it is called ) as a scope and you will also receive this in your initial login call.
I think the more important part is that you manage to authorize a user and with the token you can make the api calls really easily - even without socialite then.

Comment: @CBroe I'm strying to do something like using getHttpStatusCode() to get the status code, then act accordinally, but I can't seem to use the function it says class not found, I'm calling it like so Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException::getHttpStatusCode()

Comment: Just do a var_dump of the $e parameter (in both catch branches) to see what kind of exception object you are actually dealing with.

Comment: @Cbroe the error isn't coming from either branch, I tested like you said, same result. I thought about using the de-authorization call back Facebook provides, but i'm in a local environment any can't test. I wan't to use the getHttpStatusCode() method, but can't seem to get it to work, I also used    $debugToken = $fb->get('/debug_token?input_token=' . $token);
   // $debugTokenResponse = $debugToken->getGraphNode()->asArray(); but keeps telling me i need to provide access_token from developer, its weird because when i run something like $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=permissions'); it work